# How do I download a corrupted package again?

Tags: package-management

Ubuntu 12.04 can't install Firefox 13 update, because the package is corrupted. While attempting to install, returns this error (I translated it from my language to English).

```
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
    W: Waited for dpkg --assert-multi-arch but was not there - dpkgGo (10: There are no "child" processes).
```

I can tell that the package at `/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb` is corrupted, but even as admin, I can't delete it in order to be downloaded again.

How should I proceed?

EDIT: There was a single package causing this conflict, please report here to understand all the situation: [Why can't I install from software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149596/why-cant-i-install-from-software-center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `firefox` in the Software Center then reinstall.

Or open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

This will also uninstall firefox and its packages then you can reinstall.

Comment: It could be, but I would like to keep all my bookmarks, themes and add-ons and if I remove it I will lose all that and have to reinstall again...

Comment: no you won't. As long as you keep your .Mozilla folder in your /home then your preferences and bookmarks will be saved.

Comment: Hum, I didn't know... I'll give it a try

Comment: You're right @leousa it keeps everything as long as the .Mozilla folder is present at home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could download and install Synaptic Package Manager from Software Center. It can install or remove individual packages--you would need to find the name of the package and just search for it.